# Python Dash HTML Element formatting

Tags: python, html, plotly-dash

I am completely new to dash and frontend. I am a data engineer, but I was asked to build a frontend something like this:
[image]

And I was able to get like below:
[image]

As you can see, in the first image the checklist elements are in order and in the same horizontal line as the search keyword but in my case its down. Like, in study setting, "in vitro" in image 1 is at the same line but mine is below it. How can I create layout that gives me the image 1 output. Here is my layout code:

```
app.layout = html.Div([

    # activated once/week or when page refreshed
    html.Div(children=[html.H1(children='Data Search',style={'textAlign':'center'})]),
    html.Div(children=[html.Div(children=[html.B("Search:"),dcc.Input(placeholder="Enter a value...",type='text',id='input-on-submit',style={"margin-left": "25px"})])]),
    html.Br(),
    html.Div(children=[html.P(children="Additional Search Criteria")]),
    html.Br(),
    html.Div(children=[html.Div(
                                children=[html.B("Study Setting:",
                                          style={"margin-left": "15px"}),
                                          dcc.Checklist
                                          (id='study-setting',options=[{"label":"in vitro","value":"in vitro"},{"label":"ex vivo","value":"ex vivo"},{"label":"in vivo","value":"in vivo"}],
                                          inline=True)
                                          ])],style={"border-style": "solid","border-width": "1px"}),
    html.Div(children=[html.Div(
                                children=[html.B("Study Type:",
                                          style={"margin-left": "15px"}),
                                          dcc.Checklist
                                          (id='study-type',options=[{"label":"pharmacodynamics","value":"pharmacodynamics"},{"label":"safety pharmacology","value":"safety pharmacology"},{"label":"pharmacokinectics(PK)","value":"pharmacokinectics"}],
                                          inline=True)
                                          ])],style={"border-style": "solid","border-width": "1px"}),
    html.Div(children=[html.Div(
                                children=[html.B("Tox Study Type:",
                                          style={"margin-left": "15px"}),
                                          dcc.Checklist
                                          (id='tox-study-type',options=[{"label":"single dose","value":"single dose"},{"label":"repeat dose","value":"repeat dose"},{"label":"genotoxicity)","value":"genotoxicity"},{"label":"fertility & early embryonic development (segment |||)","value":"fertility & early embryonic development (segment |||)"},{"label":"embryo-fetal development (segment ||)","value":"embryo-fetal development (segment ||)"},{"label":"local tolerance","value":"local tolerance"},{"label":"hemocompatibility","value":"hemocompatibility"}],
                                          inline=True)
                                          ])],style={"border-style": "solid","border-width": "1px"}),])
```

Also, you can see that some keywords are long like "fertility & early embryonic development (segment |||)" but its automatically adjusted to come in next line so that if there are more keywords, it comes in the same border.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Ashish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If elements are placed side-by-side or one-above-another is affected by value of [`display`](https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/pr_class_display.asp) CSS property. First can be achieved using `inline` and second using `block`, consider following simple example

```html
<b style="display:inline">First</b>
<b style="display:inline">Second</b>
<b style="display:block">Third</b>
<b style="display:inline">Fourth</b>
```

Observe that when you have 2 `inline` elements next to each other (First and Second) they appear in single line, but as `block` element (Third) takes whole width next `inline` element is on next line.

In your case add `"display":"inline"` to styles of your `html.B`s and `dcc.Checklist`s

Comment: Thanks @Daweo. I am now able to get the keywords in a single line. Is it possible to separate the options with spaces in between? Like in image one they are evenly split.